# JSP onclick event before passing the variable it updates in link

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a link in a jsp that looks like this:

```
<a href="link?var1=foo&var2=bar"target="_blank">text</a>
```

I have a form submit `submitFormAsync('Form');` that sets a variable `${design.textVar}`

How can I set an onclick for this link to submit the form and then pass me the updated variable call it var3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update your link's href then it must have an id in order for JavaScrpt to find it:

```
<a id="lnk" href="link?var1=foo&var2=bar" onclick="update();" target="_blank">text</a>
```

And then append your value to the href:

```
function update()
{
  var link = document.getElementById("lnk");
  link.href += "&var3=" + ${design.textVar};
  return;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

If your var3 value is retrieved asyncronously, then you don't need to use JSP variables, but use pure JavaScript:

```
function update()
{
  var link = document.getElementById("lnk");
  var result = submitFormAsync('Form');
  link.href += "&var3=" + result;
  return;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the function to my js file with an extra line for submitFormAsync('Form'); but var3 came through null. May just be syntax of the link.href line

Comment: if you assign a JS variable, then you don't need ${...}.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting somewhere; on the updated example, if I type text in var result = "test text" it comes through fine, but when i put var result = ${design.textVar} or var result = design.textVar which is my name for the <textarea> in the form I get nothing.

Comment: ${design.textVar} is rendered when JSP is rendered. So, obviously it does not have a value of your async from submit. You need to use pure JS in order to get value from any of your document elements that are updated after the client has loaded the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function update()
   {
        var link = document.getElementById("lnk");
        var var3 = submitFormAsync('Form');

       var url =  link.href + "&var3=" +var3; 
       document.Form.action = url;
       document.Form.submit();  

  }
```